# One to one Relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have two entities which require a relationship. I have set the models up like this along with my `ApplicationDbContext`. However when I try and run a query against it to get data from the related entity, I get this error.

> The dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one relationship between 'Fixture.Result' and 'Result.Fixture'. To identify the dependent side of the relationship, configure the foreign key property

How can I get this to work?

I need the `Fixture`to *optionally* have a `Result`, but a `Result` *must* have a `Fixture`.

**Fixture.cs**

```
public class Fixture
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public League League { get; set; }
    public Season Season { get; set; }
    public Result Result { get; set; }
    //Properties omitted for brevity
}
```

**Result.cs**

```
public class Result
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public League League { get; set; }
    public SeasonDivision Division { get; set; }
    public SeasonCalendarDate SeasonCalendarDate { get; set; }
    public Fixture Fixture { get; set; }
    //Properties omotted for brevity
}
```

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
builder.Entity<Result>()
    .HasOne(i => i.Fixture);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

config your model as follows:

```cs
builder.Entity<Fixture>()
            .HasOne(r => r.Result)
            .WithOne(f => f.Fixture)
            .HasForeignKey<Result>(r => r.Id);
```

Comment: I then receive this error whentrying to query against the database: `System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.`

Comment: What query do you execute?

Comment: Updated the question to include the query

Comment: Please create new question , because the answer to your original question has been given and it is not related to this issue so I can answer it. And choose this answer as the correct answer

Comment: I can only post 1 question every 90 minutes, I will post a link to it when I am able to submit it

Comment: I will answer you soon after creating a new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77601710/system-invalidoperationexception-nullable-object-must-have-a-value-in-entity-fr

Answer (score 0):

In most scenarios, Entity Framework can automatically detect and configure one-to-one relationships without explicit configuration using Fluent API.

Consider the following classes representing a one-to-one relationship:

```cs
    public class Fixture
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public League League { get; set; }
        public Season Season { get; set; }
        public Result Result { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public League League { get; set; }
        public SeasonDivision Division { get; set; }
        public SeasonCalendarDate SeasonCalendarDate { get; set; }
    
        public long FixtureId { get; set; } // Foreign key property
        public Fixture Fixture { get; set; }
    }
```

This Fluent API configuration is optional in most cases, as Entity Framework can infer the relationship. However, it can be useful for customization or to adhere to specific naming conventions..

```cs
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Fixture> Fixtures { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Result> Results { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      // To explicitly configure the one-to-one relationship
      // using Fluent API in your DbContext: 
      // (below code may be optional in your case)
        modelBuilder.Entity<Fixture>()
            .HasOne(f => f.Result)
            .WithOne(r => r.Fixture)
            .HasForeignKey<Result>(r => r.FixtureId);
    }
}
```

Example to perform eager loading and retrieve fixtures with associated results:

```cs
var fixturesWithResults = dbContext.Fixtures
                                    .Include(f => f.Result)
                                    .ToList();
```