# System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value in Entity Framework query

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have two entities related database entities. I have set the models up like this along with my `ApplicationDbContext`. However when I try and run a query against it to get data from the related entity, I get this error.

> System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.

How can I get this to work?

Query:

```
var fixtures = await _context.Fixtures
                             .Where(i => i.HomeTeam.Id == seasonteamid || 
                                         i.AwayTeam.Id == seasonteamid)
                             .Select(i => new Match
                                          {
                                              ReferenceId = i.Id,
                                              MatchType = MatchType.League,
                                              DateTime = i.SeasonCalendarDate.Date,
                                              DateName = i.SeasonCalendarDate.Name,
                                              MatchDetails = i.Division.Name,
                                              HomeTeamName = i.HomeTeam.TeamName,
                                              AwayTeamName = i.AwayTeam.TeamName,
                                              HomeTeamId = i.HomeTeam.Id,
                                              AwayTeamId = i.AwayTeam.Id,
                                              HomeFrameScore = i.Result.HomeScore,
                                              AwayFrameScore = i.Result.AwayScore,
                                              MatchStatus = i.MatchStatus,
                                              LeagueId = i.League.Id
                                         })
                             .ToListAsync();
```

`Fixture.cs`:

```
public class Fixture
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public League League { get; set; }
    public Season Season { get; set; }
    public Result Result { get; set; }
    //Properties omitted for brevity
}
```

`Result.cs`:

```
public class Result
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public League League { get; set; }
    public SeasonDivision Division { get; set; }
    public SeasonCalendarDate SeasonCalendarDate { get; set; }
    public Fixture Fixture { get; set; }
    //Properties omitted for brevity
}
```

`ApplicationDbContext.cs`:

```
builder.Entity<Result>()
       .HasOne(i => i.Fixture)
       .WithOne(a => a.Result)
       .HasForeignKey<Fixture>(c => c.Id);
```

Comment: Something missed here. Such exception appear when you are trying to assign nullable field to not nullable property.

Comment: There are many similar questions. The usual suspects, assignments like `i.SeasonCalendarDate.Date`. `Date` can be not nullable, but if `SeasonCalendarDate` can be null the result evaluates as `DateTime?` which may not match `Fixture.DateTime`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I will shoot... some Fixtures doesn't have Results

here youre saing that `each Fixture need to have according Result`, and vice versa, `each Result have to have Fixture` - and even more, they need to be pair with one-to-one relations (no more, no less)

```
builder.Entity<Result>()
    .HasOne(i => i.Fixture)
    .WithOne(a => a.Result)
    .HasForeignKey<Fixture>(c => c.Id);
```

If there is a case when some of them doesn't have a pair or have more then one... it will not work.

and I think here `Result` for some record/s is null

```
HomeFrameScore = i.Result.HomeScore,
AwayFrameScore = i.Result.AwayScore,
```

Comment: Ok, but how do I make it so Result is optional? Its in a sports context, a fixture being a match between 2 teams, a result being the result of that match. So fixtures can exist without results?

Comment: Here you can see how to configure "one-to-one-or-zero" relationship: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54985656/8507722
But still in code you need to handle null for Result, eg. with "?"
`HomeFrameScore = i.Result?.HomeScore,`
`AwayFrameScore = i.Result?.AwayScore,`

Comment: Also in Microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/one-to-one#optional-one-to-one

Comment: > So fixtures can exist without results?
This I don't know, I don't know domain :/

But you should debug and check if there is a record where Results is null